# How can I access the native share icon in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to get access to the native iOS/android share icons? 
I rather not pull in extra package or add an extra icon file if it's already provided by the OS.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this?](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share)

Comment: @MattyK React Native has sharing bulit-in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html  I'm asking for access to just generic share icon for ios without importing one: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ei-share-apple.svg

Comment: see this:  http://discuss.nativebase.io/t/where-to-get-the-list-of-icon-names-used-in-native-base/37